# MySQL sort values that contain two numbers separated by "x"

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have some values consisting of decimal numbers and alphabets:

```
2mm
3x4mm
2.5x5mm
1.7x6mm
1.7x9mm
1.6x5mm
3mm
5mm
3.5x5mm
3.5x8mm
10x7mm
```

Note: x - means alphabet `x`. I want to sort them ascending so that the result looks like:

```
1.6x5mm
1.7x6mm
1.7x9mm
2mm
2.5x5mm
3mm
3x4mm
3.5x5mm
3.5x8mm
5mm
10x7mm
```

So I need both decimal and alphanumerical sorting.

Comment: You should consider an other data representation for that. You can not support ordering this by e.g. an index in an easy way.

Comment: You could `ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(column_name, 'x', '') AS DECIMAL)`, perhaps?

Comment: Ideally you would multiply both numbers so that they are sorted by largest area.

Comment: Hi jack, It does not work. Result is Worng.

Comment: DB result was like this(WRONG SORTING) ---Jack   
Full Texts value
  2mm
  3x4mm
  2.5x5mm
  1.7x6mm
  1.7x9mm
  1.6x5mm
  3mm
  5mm
  3.5x5mm
  3.5x8mm
  10x7mm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [MySQL string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). For example, you can use `LOCATE` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions to separate the two numbers:

```sql
/*
CREATE TABLE test (value VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL);
INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES
    ('2mm'),
    ('3x4mm'),
    ('2.5x5mm'),
    ('1.7x6mm'),
    ('1.7x9mm'),
    ('1.6x5mm'),
    ('3mm'),
    ('5mm'),
    ('3.5x5mm'),
    ('3.5x8mm'),
    ('10x7mm');
*/

SELECT
    value, 
    1 * CASE WHEN LOCATE('x', value) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, 'x', 1) ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, 'mm', 1) END AS x,
    1 * CASE WHEN LOCATE('x', value) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, 'x', -1), 'mm', 1) ELSE NULL END AS y
FROM test
ORDER BY x, y
```

For illustration I have placed the calculations inside the select clause instead of order by clause. The result:

```
+---------+------+------+
| value   | x    | y    |
+---------+------+------+
| 1.6x5mm |  1.6 |    5 |
| 1.7x6mm |  1.7 |    6 |
| 1.7x9mm |  1.7 |    9 |
| 2mm     |    2 | NULL |
| 2.5x5mm |  2.5 |    5 |
| 3mm     |    3 | NULL |
| 3x4mm   |    3 |    4 |
| 3.5x5mm |  3.5 |    5 |
| 3.5x8mm |  3.5 |    8 |
| 5mm     |    5 | NULL |
| 10x7mm  |   10 |    7 |
+---------+------+------+
```

Comment: Dear Salman A. : Thanks lot.. It is correct one,                                      SELECT
    value, 
    1 * CASE WHEN LOCATE('x', value) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, 'x', 1) ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, 'mm', 1) END AS x,
    1 * CASE WHEN LOCATE('x', value) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, 'x', -1), 'mm', 1) ELSE NULL END AS y
FROM test
ORDER BY x, y

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following two methods to strip out everything before the x (and replace mm with nothing)

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE('3x4mm', 'mm', ''),'x',-1);

THE REPLACE function is to clean out the unit (mm), and to get the first set(everything before the x) I use the SUBSTRING_INDEX method to get everything up to the 'x' and then you can sort with this result.

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html